# I am running into this error with Python Selenium with the timing of the webpage load

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, web

```
# Path to the chromedriver program
service = Service('C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\chromedriver.exe')
service.start()

# Driver opens the remote with robinhood website
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url)
driver.get('https://robinhood.com/crypto/BTC')

# We will grab the element id's to log on to Robinhood
# driver.find_element_by_id(“ID”).send_keys(“username”)
# driver.find_element_by_id (“ID”).send_keys(“password”)
# driver.find_element_by_id(“submit”).click()
signinButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "_3kh8OsNx6QdAbMaoKTi2Yq _1uaripz9PIQ8yApSTs6BKk")))

# driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3kh8OsNx6QdAbMaoKTi2Yq _1uaripz9PIQ8yApSTs6BKk')
signinButton.click()

# Closes the driver after timeout
driver.quit()
```

I am basically opening up chrome webdriver and going to the robinhood website, however I am running into a webpage load issue. In order to fix it I was attempting to use WebDriverWait to halt the button click until the webpage loads.

The problem is the button click does not execute once 10 secs pass and instead throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/gitRepos/bitmine/runmine.py", line 25, in <module>
    signinButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "_3kh8OsNx6QdAbMaoKTi2Yq _1uaripz9PIQ8yApSTs6BKk")))
  File "D:\Programs Files 2\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: well increase the timeout. selenium were unable to locate the element within the time specified, also don't use white space within class name. use `.`

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη where would I insert the period would it be like this: "_3kh8OsNx6QdAbMaoKTi2Yq._1uaripz9PIQ8yApSTs6BKk" ?

Comment: check below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs due to syncghronization issue. Yu can resolved your issue by using waits in selenium. Please refer below solution to avoid such errors:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='_3kh8OsNx6QdAbMaoKTi2Yq _1uaripz9PIQ8yApSTs6BKk']"))).click()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

**Section for Sign up for free button:**

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='_3kh8OsNx6QdAbMaoKTi2Yq _1uaripz9PIQ8yApSTs6BKk']"))).click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Sign up for free')]"))).click()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just had a question, there is another button after this one that throws the same error. I copied the same line and changed the timeout to 40 but it did not work.

Comment: Which button sign up for free/ watch BTC?

Comment: There is a button that opens after in that div with log in that throws another timeout exception.

Comment: Please tell me name atm I can see Watch BTC button  is there

Comment: This is the class name of the button: rh-hyperlink _2uFNhgQu5JhaCtiNU8posI xgzdGyr8bFpObMnpLZh5g

Comment: If you click the "Sign up to buy" button a div will popup and the log in button is within this

Comment: Please find updated Section for handling next buttoon after clicking on Sign up to buy  button:

Comment: Thank you! It took some tweaking but I got it working now with your help!

Answer (score 1):

That error means it did not find a clickable button within the 10 seconds, and it Timed Out, throwing a TimeoutException. You need to set a longer wait time, or handle the TimeoutException accordingly

Comment: Initially it did have a timeout error and I fixed using the .until, but how would I handle the timeout exception if I need it to click that button? Sorry I am new to selenium!

Comment: You could use a try, except and while loop until the button has been clicked.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that selenium were unable to locate the element within the time specified.

Also don't use spaces within class name. just use dot `.` otherwise whatever you increased the time, selenium will not be able to find it .

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://robinhood.com/crypto/BTC")

element = driver.find_element_by_class_name(
    "_3kh8OsNx6QdAbMaoKTi2Yq._1uaripz9PIQ8yApSTs6BKk")

print(element)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I added the "." like you said and tried increasing the wait to 50 secs. However now it opens the page and closes immediately.

Comment: @user2304873 remove the last line within my code which is `driver.quit()` and if your final target is to click on the button. just end the element line with `.click()`. you don't need to specify a time since `driver.get()` will actually wait till the page loads. I've been able to locate the element without using time delay at all

Comment: Thank you so much that worked now! I think I understand whats going on too appreciate this help

Answer (score 1):

The error usually spit out due to not able to find the object within defined time period.  I rather you set up an exception error to catch it and proceed to find next object or element if it fails.

```
try:
    #Insert your scraping action here
    signinButton.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
```